# Mac mini connected display not showing full screen

Tags: mac, display, macos, mac-mini

I just got the new Mac Mini and plugged in my display, but it's not showing the full screen.

Here's how it looks like:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **System Preferences** → **Displays** and adjust the **Overscan** slider (or checkbox, depending on the screen model) so the content fits on the screen. Alternatively, you should be able to change the settings on the display itself to adjust the overscan.

For more information on overscan and underscan, see the Apple KB article:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5841